# Copy on click of a radio button

Tags: javascript, copy

I have the following code on a button:

```
<html> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function copy()

{ `enter code here`
    var field1 = document.getElementById("Field1"); 
    var field2 = document.getElementById("Field2"); 
    var field3 = document.getElementById("Field3");
    Field2.value = `${Field2.value}\n\r${Field1.value}-${Field3.value}`;
    Field1.value = ''
    Field3.value = ''
 } 
</script> 
<input type="button" value="Add Qualification" onClick="copy();" /> 
</html>
```

Now I need the same copying to be done but when the user click on a radio button which I have on the form and named "CopyText"in stead of a normal button.`enter code here`

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Marius

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same onclick event, like

```
 <input type="radio" value="CopyText" onclick="copy()" />
```